# Cypher query to get nodes with given property values

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-graph, cypher

Being new to Cypher Queries on Spring Data Graph, this may be quite trivial...

I am looking for what would be the Cypher query to fetch all nodes that have a given value for a couple of properties. So, what would be `???` in the @Query annotation for the following:

```
@Query(???)
List<MyObject> findByProperty1AndProperty2(String property1, String property2)
```

**EDIT:**
So, I managed to use the derived queries by adding Cypher dependencies (as suggested by Michael below). But I seem to be getting the below error:

`string matching regex (?i)\Qreturn\E' expected but ,' found`

I think this is because it seems to be creating a query like :

`start n=node:__types__(className="com.example.MyObject") where n.property1 = {0}, n.property2 = {1} return n`

rather than

`start n=node:__types__(className="com.example.MyObject") where n.property1 = {0} and n.property2 = {1} return n`

(Note the `,` instead of `and` in the query)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take into account that global queries are not the sweet spot of Neo4j, but as you're running Spring Data Neo4j that is alleviated a bit. :)

Actually you don't need a `@Query` annotation for this query.

It constructs a derived query anyway looking at your properties, if one is indexed it will use that one as starting point for your query otherwise it will pull all entries from the "`__type__`"-index.

Actually it will create a query like:

```
start n=node:__types__(className="com.example.MyObject")
where n.property1 = {0} and n.property2 = {1} 
return n
```

So if you're using the current snapshot build of SDN (which will be released as RC1 this week.
You can just do:

```
List<MyObject> findByProperty1AndProperty2(String property1, String property2)
```

Sure cypher and gremlin are optional dependencies in SDN (b/c some people don't want to pull scala / groovy in by default). You just have to add the maven dependency for cypher to your project

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
   <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, @Michael! But as mentioned in another post, when I use derived queries, I get an error - "Cypher is not available, please add it to your dependencies". Any ideas why?  (I am using SDN 2.0.0.M1)

Comment: after adding the dependency I am getting an error like : `string matching regex `(?i)\Qreturn\E' expected but `,' found`

Comment: i think the reason is because it seems to be creating a query like : `start n=node:__types__(className="com.example.MyObject") where n.property1 = {0}, n.property2 = {1} return n` rather than `start n=node:__types__(className="com.example.MyObject") where n.property1 = {0} and n.property2 = {1} return n` . Note the `,` instead of `and` in my query

Comment: Can you raise a JIRA issue for that? Thanks a lot.